# Add classname to Gutenberg block wrapper in the editor?

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to create custom columns block in Gutenberg.
Is it possible to add class to the wrapper of the element in the editor based on the attributes? I'd like to switch `???` to class based e.g. `columns-4`. Otherwise it's not possible to use `flex`.

```
<div id="..." class="wp-block editor-block-list__block ???" data-type="my-blocks/column" tabindex="0" aria-label="Block: Single Column">
 <div>
      <div class="this-can-be-set-in-edit-or-attributes">
         ...
     </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the existing columns block built in already uses flex

Comment: @TomJNowell you can't change size of the column there though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it can be done with the [filter](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock):

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const withCustomClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        if(props.attributes.size) {
            return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ "block-" + props.attributes.size } />;
        } else {
            return <BlockListBlock {...props} />
        }

    };
}, 'withClientIdClassName' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'my-plugin/with-client-id-class-name', withCustomClassName );
```

Comment: Shouldn't the callback at the end of `wp.hooks.addFilter` be `withCustomClassName` instead `withClientIdClassName`?

Answer (score 6):

I think is also possible to manage wrapper classes with useBlockProps.
I found this solution in the official Gutenberg doc, [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#block-wrapper-props)

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

// ...
const blockSettings = {
apiVersion: 2,

// ...

edit: () => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
        className: 'my-random-classname',
    } );

    return <div { ...blockProps }>Your block.</div>;
},
};
```